# gunicorn: proc_name not working

Tags: gunicorn, salt-stack

I'm running gunicorn with django and nginx and deploying with salt.

I want change gunicorn's proc name so I made a config file with python

```
gunicorn_config.py

bind = ...
workers = ...
proc_name = 'Name'
daemon = True
...
```

and in salt state file,

```
gunicorn_config_file:
  file.managed:
   - name: /etc/gunicorn_config.py
   - source: salt://.../files/gunicorn_config.py
   - template: jinja
```

and runs it

```
start_gunicorn:
  cmd.run:
    - name: '{{venv}}/gunicorn -c /etc/gunicorn_conig.py myProject.wsgi'
    - cwd: /path/to/django/project
```

the minion returns all succeed but the process name of gunicorn is still
`gunicorn: master` and `gunicorn: worker`

Other configurations like workers are working well, but proc_name is not.
How can I change the proc_name properly? I installed `setproctitle` with pip in venv too.

thank you.

Comment: meh, `proc_name` not working for me either. Ill let you know if I find something

Comment: If I get this correctly it wont be a salt related issue, Have you tried to check it manually ? Like restarting the service or do the configuration manually in order to check if the configuration itself works correctly ?